# How design database for a blog ( with series post)?

Tags: database-design, blogs

I want make a blog system. I have some post, and i want group its in to a series of post? How save them in database?

```
Series             || Post
============================
name_of_searies1   || s1_part1
                      s1_part2
                      s1_part3
name_of_searies2   || s2_part1
                      s2_part2
                      s2_part3
```

Updated: My schema like this
http://www.laravelsd.com/share/s4UjqE

Updated 2: How to link the posts in the series? (like Next Post, Previous Post)

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to include your current schema (ideally in the form of CREATE TABLE statements), so that the community can help you by checking it over. If you don't yet have the knowledge to get to that point, I would advise you to start with a textbook or online tutorial on relational database design.

Comment: Hi, i have already updated. thanks u!

Answer (score 0):

It seems preety straight forward to make a table blog_series to store the series and then put a serie_id field in blog_posts to reference blog_series.

Edit for your Update 2

I would put an order field in blog_posts, that way you can make `SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE serie_id = serie ORDER BY order` then you can easily get next and previous posts.